# Topological properties of schemes

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

Let $X$ and $Y$ be Noetherian schemes over $\mathbb{C}$ and suppose there is a $1-1$-correspondence between closed points of $X$ and that of $Y$. Does this imply that the dimension of $X$ is the same as the dimension of $Y$?

Comment: probably a better condition is that of _finite type_ over C. The answer is still no, as any two varieties of positive dimension have the same cardinality of points. Perhaps something interesting happens when there is a morphism $X \to Y$, inducing a bijection on closed points, between $X$ and $Y$ of finite type. (note that if we lose quasi-compactness, then the question is again trivially false, as an infinite disjoint union of  Spec C includes in $A^1$ and induces a bijection of points). These type of mrphsms are sometimes called geometric bijectns (see eg Bridgeland's Intro to Hall algebras.

Comment: @Salvatierrez: So is it true if there is a morphism from $X$ to $Y$, say?

Comment: dunno. If they are simply noetherian then the counterexample below shows that it's false, if they are of finite type it's more plausible. Maybe you can use Chevalley's theorem and constructibility?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No. For instance, $X=\textrm{Spec }\mathbb C[[t]]$ and $Y=\textrm{Spec }\mathbb C$ both have one closed point, but $\dim X=1$ and $\dim Y=0$.

Comment: I do not understand why $X$ has only one closed point? Any ideal of the form $(t-\alpha)$ for $\alpha \in \mathbb{C}$ gives a closed point.

Comment: $t-\alpha$ is a unit unless $\alpha=0$, so the ideal it generates is the whole ring.

Comment: @user43198 That is true for $\mathbb{C}[t]$, but $X$ is the spectrum of the formal power series ring $\mathbb{C}[[t]]$. If $\alpha\neq 0$, then $(t-\alpha)$ is a unit in this ring.

Comment: @Ventullo: Thanks. However, in the question the schemes are supposes to be Noetherian.

Comment: @user43198: as you know, I answered your question *before* you added the Noetherian hypothesis.

Comment: $\textrm{Spec }\mathbb C[[t]]$  *is* Noetherian, isn't it?

Comment: @Brenin: I had edited the question shortly afterwards since the examples that I have in mind are Noetherian. Sorry for the inconvinience.

Comment: Oh, never mind. By the way @JeremyRickard is right, $\textrm{Spec }\mathbb C[[t]]$ is Noetherian.

Comment: Sorry for all the confusion.